# PETSc vectorize operations with neighboring vector values

Tags: vectorization, petsc

I'm implementing finite difference algorithm from [uFDTD book](https://github.com/john-b-schneider/uFDTD). Many FDM equations involve operations on adjoined vector elements.
For example, an update equation for electric field

```
ez[m] = ez[m] + (hy[m] - hy[m-1]) * imp0
```

uses adjoined vector values `hy[m]` and `hy[m-1]`.

How can I implement these operations in PETSc efficiently? Is there something beyond local vector loops and [scatterers](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Vec/VecScatter.html)?

Comment: Is `imp0` a constant?

Comment: @JacobFaib yes, `imp0` is constant

Comment: And `m` is a timestep or is it iterating through elements of the `Vec`?

Comment: @JacobFaib `ez` and `hy` are `Vec` vectors of the same size. `m` is a spatial index. There's no time indexes, previous time steps get overwritten by the new values.

Comment: The fastest way to do this would be to massage `hy` into a form such that you can call `VecAXPY(ez,imp0,hy)`. I would take a look at `VecGhost` for `hy` as this saves you the trouble of managing the `VecScatter` yourself. See [this example](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/src/vec/vec/tutorials/ex9.c.html) on how to set it up.

Comment: @JacobFaib Thanks!. I have ghosts setup for me by `DMDACreate1d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my goal was efficiency, I would call a stencil engine. There are many many many papers, and sometimes even open source code, for example, Devito. The idea is that PETSc manages the data structure and parallelism. Then you can feed the local data brick to your favorite stencil computer.

Comment: I will look into this. Thanks!